# Android SQLite, JSON, List for storage of constant objects

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I've got an Android app and want to store about 100-200 constant prefefined objects. The object contain name and other attributes and the user should be able to view complete list of these objects and filter them by name or by attributes. What is best option to store them? In SQLite, JSON file or maybe hardcoded final objects added to list?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that names and some attributes should be available in multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like storing them as hardcoded final objects as there is too many of them. SQLite is a DB with DB call overheads and code can inadvertently update the objects. I would prefer storing them in JSON file or XML.